# Plotting 3D regions in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to create a 3D region in MATLAB by stacking 2D curves one above the other.I have a particular 2D curve at every height location for a total height h,and I am required to place the 2D curves one above the other to get the 3D region for the height h.How can this be done?

For eg,If my curves are circles of uniformly increasing radii through a height interval [1,10] then I should be able to get a frustum of a cone of height 9.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are holding your curves in the cell array `curves` as Nx2 array:

```
cellfun(@(x) plot(x(:,1),x(:,2)),curves);
```